# MVVM and passing over optinal value to the viewModel

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to get a MVVM approach to work for my swiftui app but I have a problem where a optional variabel does not seem to get passed over correct.

So the home view you can click either on "new" or "edit", on edit I want to pass the value over, the code for this screen:
Button:

```
Button {
        selectedTag = tag
        isShowingEdit.toggle()
} label: {
         Image(systemName: "pencil")
         .font(Font.system(size: 30, weight: .bold))
         .foregroundColor(.gray)
}
```

Navigationlink:

```
  NavigationLink(destination: TagsCreatingView(viewModel: TagCreateViewModel(tag: selectedTag)), isActive: $isShowingEdit) { EmptyView() }
```

The TagCreateViewModel init looks as following:

```
  init(tag: TagMO?) {

    if let tag = tag {
    self.tag = tag
        title = tag.title
        selectedColor = Int(tag.color)
    }
```

If I do a print on selectedTag when I click the button it has the correct value, but over inte the viewModel it will be nil. Also if I click the edit button twice it works as planned and tag is not nil ( by twice I mean click edit, on the other screen click cancel then edit again..)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that inside the destination view had

@StateObject var viewModel: TagCreateViewModel

Changing it to
@ObservedObject var viewModel: TagCreateViewModel

Solved it since the ownership got put correct :9